# Navigate inputs using the arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which for some reason I can't get to work using the arrow keys (up to go to the previous tabindex, and down to go to the next tabindex).

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="booking-docket" title="Booking Docket">

    <h6>BOOKING DETAILS</h6>

        <div id="booking-docket-wrapper">

        <div class="booking-left left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PAYMENT:</p>

                <select id="txt-payment" class="input-select move right" />

                  <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                  <option value="Acc">Acc</option>
                  <option value="CC">CC</option>
                  <option value="PP">PP</option>

                </select> 

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">ACCOUNT NO:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-account" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="3"  />

            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PASSENGER:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-passenger" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="2" />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">ACC NAME:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-account-name" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="4"  />

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">TELEPHONE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-telephone" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="5"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DATE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-date" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="7"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">LEAD TIME:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-lead" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="6"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">TIME:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-min" class="input-txt-xxsml move right" tabindex="9"  />

                <input type="text" id="txt-hour" class="input-txt-xxsml move right" tabindex="8"  />

            </div>            

        </div>

    <h6>JOURNEY DETAILS</h6>

        <div class="booking-left left">

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <div title="Pickup">

                    <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PICKUP:</p>

                    <input type="text" id="txt-pickup" name="txt-pickup" class="btn-row-wrapper btn-row-wrapper addr-search-input validate-from-db input-txt-med address move right" tabindex="11"  />

                    <input type="text" id="txt-pickup-hn" class="input-txt-xsml move right" tabindex="10"  />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-pickup-pc" class="hidden-post-code" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-pickup-lat-long" class="hidden-lat-lng" />

                    <button id="cp-search-pick" class="hide" name="btn-row-wrapper" >Search</button>

                    <div class="div-result-info div-pagenation-style">

                        <label class="left">Showing results <span class="res-pgnum"></span> of <span class="res-ttlpgs"></span></label>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgup navicon" ><img src="images/nav-rght-sml.png" alt="nav-right" /></a></span>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgdn navicon" ><img src="images/nav-lft-sml.png" alt="nav-left" /></a></span>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <div title="Dropoff">

                    <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DESTINATION:</p>

                    <input type="text" id="txt-destination" class="btn-row-wrapper addr-search-input validate-from-db input-txt-med address move right" tabindex="13"  />

                    <input type="text" id="txt-destination-hn" class="input-txt-xsml move right" tabindex="12"  />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-destination-pc" class="hidden-post-code" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-destination-lat-long" class="hidden-lat-lng" />

                    <button id="cp-search-dest" class="hide" name="btn-row-wrapper" >Search</button>

                    <div class="div-result-info div-pagenation-style">

                        <label class="left">Showing results <span class="res-pgnum"></span> of <span class="res-ttlpgs"></span></label>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgup navicon" ><img src="images/nav-rght-sml.png" alt="nav-right" /></a></span>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgdn navicon" ><img src="images/nav-lft-sml.png" alt="nav-left" /></a></span>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right left">

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <div title="Via">

                    <p class="p-lbl-txt left">VIA:</p>

                    <input type="text" id="txt-via" class="btn-row-wrapper addr-search-input validate-from-db input-txt-med address move right" tabindex="15"  />

                    <input type="text" id="txt-via-hn" class="input-txt-xsml move right" tabindex="14"  />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-via-pc" class="hidden-post-code" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-via-lat-long" class="hidden-lat-lng" />

                    <button class="hide" name="btn-row-wrapper" >Search</button>

                    <div class="div-result-info div-pagenation-style">

                        <label class="left">Showing results <span class="res-pgnum"></span> of <span class="res-ttlpgs"></span></label>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgup navicon" ><img src="images/nav-rght-sml.png" alt="nav-right" /></a></span>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgdn navicon" ><img src="images/nav-lft-sml.png" alt="nav-left" /></a></span>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">TARIFF:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-tariff" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="16"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">EMAIL:</p>

                <!-- TEMP REMOVED <img id="img-email" class="left" src="images/email.png" title="Email PDF Job Receipt" />-->

                <input type="text" id="txt-email" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="17"  />

            </div>   

        </div> 

   <h6>GENERAL DETAILS</h6>

        <div class="booking-left left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DRV FARE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-drv-fare" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="18"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">CAR TYPE:</p>

                <select id="txt-cartype" class="input-select move right" tabindex="20" >

                  <option value="Car">Car</option>
                  <option value="Est">Est</option>
                  <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
                  <option value="8B">8B</option>

                </select> 

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">CLIENT FARE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-client-fare" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="19"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">FLIGHT NO:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-flight-no" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="21"  />

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">MILES:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-miles" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="22"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">CAR:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-car" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="24"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">WAITING:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-waiting" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="23"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DRIVER:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-driver" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="25"  />

            </div>

        </div>

    <h6>NOTES</h6> 

        <div class="booking-full left">

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">GENERAL NOTES:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-general" class="input-txt-lrg move right" tabindex="26"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">OFFICE NOTES:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-office" class="input-txt-lrg move right" tabindex="27"  />

            </div>

        </div>

    <h6>MISC</h6> 

        <div class="booking-left-s left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">RETURN:</p>

                <div class="check"><input type="checkbox" id="chk-return" class="test move left" name="chk-return" value="return" tabindex="28"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PRE BOOKING:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-prebook" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="29"  />

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right-s left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">NO. OF JOBS:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-nojobs" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="30"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">BOOKED BY:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-bookedby" class="input-txt-sml right" tabindex="31" value="<?php echo UserAccount::get_username(); ?>" disabled />

            </div>

        </div>

        <p id="p-reference-no" class="text-align-center"></p>

    </div> 

</div>

<!-- End of Booking Docket -->
```

jQuery

```
// Navigate Docket using Keys

var keyUp = 38;
var keyDown = 40;

$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        // Key up function
        if (e.keyCode == keyUp) {      
            $(".move:focus").next().focus();

        }
        if (e.keyCode == keyDown) {      
            $(".move:focus").prev().focus();

        }
    }
);
```

I've basically added a class called 'move' to all the input values, but for some reason this is not working for me at all. Any help would be much appreciated!

It appears to work two of the boxes, i.e. pickup house no to pickup address, but not for any of the other text boxes.

Here is the jsfiddle link; http://jsfiddle.net/kwx6u8w4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that should do what you're trying to do.
The problem with the $(".move:focus").next().focus(); is that the .move elements has to be sibblings.

```js
$(function  (){
    var keyUp = 38;
    var keyDown = 40;
    
    $(document).keydown(
        function(e)
        {
            var moves = $(".move");
            // Key up function
            if (e.keyCode == keyDown) {
                for(i = 0; i <= moves.length; i++) {
                    if (moves[i] == $(".move:focus").get(0)) {
                       $(moves[i + 1]).focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode == keyUp) {
                for(i = 0; i <= moves.length; i++) {
                    if (moves[i] == $(".move:focus").get(0)) {
                       $(moves[i - 1]).focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="booking-docket" title="Booking Docket">

    <h6>BOOKING DETAILS</h6>

        <div id="booking-docket-wrapper">

        <div class="booking-left left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PAYMENT:</p>

                <select id="txt-payment" class="input-select move right" />

                  <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                  <option value="Acc">Acc</option>
                  <option value="CC">CC</option>
                  <option value="PP">PP</option>

                </select> 

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">ACCOUNT NO:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-account" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="3"  />

            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PASSENGER:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-passenger" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="2" />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">ACC NAME:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-account-name" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="4"  />

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">TELEPHONE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-telephone" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="5"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DATE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-date" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="7"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">LEAD TIME:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-lead" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="6"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">TIME:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-min" class="input-txt-xxsml move right" tabindex="9"  />

                <input type="text" id="txt-hour" class="input-txt-xxsml move right" tabindex="8"  />

            </div>            

        </div>

    <h6>JOURNEY DETAILS</h6>

        <div class="booking-left left">

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <div title="Pickup">

                    <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PICKUP:</p>

                    <input type="text" id="txt-pickup" name="txt-pickup" class="btn-row-wrapper btn-row-wrapper addr-search-input validate-from-db input-txt-med address move right" tabindex="11"  />

                    <input type="text" id="txt-pickup-hn" class="input-txt-xsml move right" tabindex="10"  />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-pickup-pc" class="hidden-post-code" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-pickup-lat-long" class="hidden-lat-lng" />

                    <button id="cp-search-pick" class="hide" name="btn-row-wrapper" >Search</button>

                    <div class="div-result-info div-pagenation-style">

                        <label class="left">Showing results <span class="res-pgnum"></span> of <span class="res-ttlpgs"></span></label>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgup navicon" ><img src="images/nav-rght-sml.png" alt="nav-right" /></a></span>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgdn navicon" ><img src="images/nav-lft-sml.png" alt="nav-left" /></a></span>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <div title="Dropoff">

                    <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DESTINATION:</p>

                    <input type="text" id="txt-destination" class="btn-row-wrapper addr-search-input validate-from-db input-txt-med address move right" tabindex="13"  />

                    <input type="text" id="txt-destination-hn" class="input-txt-xsml move right" tabindex="12"  />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-destination-pc" class="hidden-post-code" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-destination-lat-long" class="hidden-lat-lng" />

                    <button id="cp-search-dest" class="hide" name="btn-row-wrapper" >Search</button>

                    <div class="div-result-info div-pagenation-style">

                        <label class="left">Showing results <span class="res-pgnum"></span> of <span class="res-ttlpgs"></span></label>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgup navicon" ><img src="images/nav-rght-sml.png" alt="nav-right" /></a></span>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgdn navicon" ><img src="images/nav-lft-sml.png" alt="nav-left" /></a></span>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right left">

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <div title="Via">

                    <p class="p-lbl-txt left">VIA:</p>

                    <input type="text" id="txt-via" class="btn-row-wrapper addr-search-input validate-from-db input-txt-med address move right" tabindex="15"  />

                    <input type="text" id="txt-via-hn" class="input-txt-xsml move right" tabindex="14"  />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-via-pc" class="hidden-post-code" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="txt-via-lat-long" class="hidden-lat-lng" />

                    <button class="hide" name="btn-row-wrapper" >Search</button>

                    <div class="div-result-info div-pagenation-style">

                        <label class="left">Showing results <span class="res-pgnum"></span> of <span class="res-ttlpgs"></span></label>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgup navicon" ><img src="images/nav-rght-sml.png" alt="nav-right" /></a></span>

                        <span class="right"><a href="#" class="lbl-addr-pgdn navicon" ><img src="images/nav-lft-sml.png" alt="nav-left" /></a></span>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">TARIFF:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-tariff" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="16"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">EMAIL:</p>

                <!-- TEMP REMOVED <img id="img-email" class="left" src="images/email.png" title="Email PDF Job Receipt" />-->

                <input type="text" id="txt-email" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="17"  />

            </div>   

        </div> 

   <h6>GENERAL DETAILS</h6>

        <div class="booking-left left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DRV FARE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-drv-fare" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="18"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">CAR TYPE:</p>

                <select id="txt-cartype" class="input-select move right" tabindex="20" >

                  <option value="Car">Car</option>
                  <option value="Est">Est</option>
                  <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
                  <option value="8B">8B</option>

                </select> 

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">CLIENT FARE:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-client-fare" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="19"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">FLIGHT NO:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-flight-no" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="21"  />

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">MILES:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-miles" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="22"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">CAR:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-car" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="24"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">WAITING:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-waiting" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="23"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">DRIVER:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-driver" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="25"  />

            </div>

        </div>

    <h6>NOTES</h6> 

        <div class="booking-full left">

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">GENERAL NOTES:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-general" class="input-txt-lrg move right" tabindex="26"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-3 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">OFFICE NOTES:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-office" class="input-txt-lrg move right" tabindex="27"  />

            </div>

        </div>

    <h6>MISC</h6> 

        <div class="booking-left-s left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">RETURN:</p>

                <div class="check"><input type="checkbox" id="chk-return" class="test move left" name="chk-return" value="return" tabindex="28"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">PRE BOOKING:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-prebook" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="29"  />

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="booking-right-s left">

            <div class="col-1 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">NO. OF JOBS:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-nojobs" class="input-txt-sml move right" tabindex="30"  />

            </div>

            <div class="col-2 left">

                <p class="p-lbl-txt left">BOOKED BY:</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt-bookedby" class="input-txt-sml right" tabindex="31" value="<?php echo UserAccount::get_username(); ?>" disabled />

            </div>

        </div>

        <p id="p-reference-no" class="text-align-center"></p>

    </div> 

</div>

<!-- End of Booking Docket -->
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Is there any way to disable it changing the select option when you key press away from it